# C# HTTPS Proxy using TCP

Tags: c#, .net, https, proxy

I am trying to implement a HTTPS proxy using C#. The proxy should only support HTTPS, not HTTP. As far as I know, a HTTPListener is not a good choice, as you need a SSL certificate for it to support HTTPS, which a proxy usually does not provide.

I am using a TcpListener and TcpClients. Here's the code I got so far:

```
   protected void HandleTCPRequest(object clientObject)
    {
        TcpClient inClient = clientObject as TcpClient;
        TcpClient outClient = null;

        try
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream = inClient.GetStream();
            StreamReader clientReader = new StreamReader(clientStream);
            StreamWriter clientWriter = new StreamWriter(clientStream);

            // Read initial request.
            List<String> connectRequest = new List<string>();
            string line;
            while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line = clientReader.ReadLine()))
            {
                connectRequest.Add(line);
            }
            if (connectRequest.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            string[] requestLine0Split = connectRequest[0].Split(' ');
            if (requestLine0Split.Length < 3)
            {
                return;
            }
            // Check if it is CONNECT
            string method = requestLine0Split[0];
            if (!method.Equals("CONNECT"))
            {
                return;
            }
            // Get host and port
            string requestUri = requestLine0Split[1];
            string[] uriSplit = requestUri.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (uriSplit.Length < 2)
            {
                return;
            }
            string host = uriSplit[0];
            int port = Int32.Parse(uriSplit[1]);

            // Connect to server
            outClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
            NetworkStream serverStream = outClient.GetStream();
            StreamWriter serverWriter = new StreamWriter(serverStream);
            StreamReader serverReader = new StreamReader(serverStream);

            // Send 200 Connection Established to Client
            clientWriter.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n");
            clientWriter.Flush();

            Logger.Debug("Established TCP connection for " + host);

            while (true)
            {
                line = clientReader.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    Logger.Debug("->Server: " + line);
                    serverWriter.WriteLine(line);
                }
                line = serverReader.ReadLine();
                if (line != null)
                {
                    Logger.Debug("->Client: " + line);
                    clientWriter.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // Disconnent if connections still alive
            try
            {
                if (inClient.Connected)
                {
                    inClient.Close();
                }
                if (outClient != null && outClient.Connected)
                {
                    outClient.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Warn("Could not close the tcp connection: ", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

The incoming connections are accepted in another method.

**EDIT**: I made some changes. Now, the client starts sending SSL data, but the server never responds. After some time, the client just opens a new connection and tries again. The output I get:

```
Established TCP connection for www.google.de
->Server: ▬♥☺ ?☺  ?♥☺R'"??????#☼}~??♣|]?
->Server: ??_5OL(??  H ??
->Server: ?¶ ? ? 9 8?☼?♣ ? 5??      ?◄?‼ E D 3 2?♀?♫?☻?♦ ? A ♣ ♦ /?↕ ▬ ‼?
->Server: ?♥??
->Server: ☺  0   ↕ ►
->Server: www.google.de
->Server: ♠ ↨ ↑ ↓ ♂ ☻☺  #  3t
```

I'm open for other suggestions than a TCP listener. Thanks!

Comment: The draft you are referring to is obsolete as CONNECT command is part of HTTP 1.1. You are recommended to check the corresponding RFC for HTTP 1.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it working. Dealing with the SSL data with StreamReader/StreamWriter was wrong. The data was converted to strings and thereby errors appeard (I assume). Using the `NetworkStream.Read` and`NetworkStream.Write` methods with `byte[]` did it.

Here's the code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles a TCP request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientObject">The tcp client from the accepted connection.</param>
    protected void HandleTCPRequest(object clientObject)
    {
        TcpClient inClient = clientObject as TcpClient;
        TcpClient outClient = null;

        try
        {
            NetworkStream clientStream = inClient.GetStream();
            StreamReader clientReader = new StreamReader(clientStream);
            StreamWriter clientWriter = new StreamWriter(clientStream);

            // Read initial request.
            List<String> connectRequest = new List<string>();
            string line;
            while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line = clientReader.ReadLine()))
            {
                connectRequest.Add(line);
            }
            if (connectRequest.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }

            string[] requestLine0Split = connectRequest[0].Split(' ');
            if (requestLine0Split.Length < 3)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            // Check if it is CONNECT
            string method = requestLine0Split[0];
            if (!method.Equals("CONNECT"))
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            // Get host and port
            string requestUri = requestLine0Split[1];
            string[] uriSplit = requestUri.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (uriSplit.Length < 2)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            string host = uriSplit[0];
            int port = Int32.Parse(uriSplit[1]);

            // Connect to server
            outClient = new TcpClient(host, port);

            // Send 200 Connection Established to Client
            clientWriter.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n");
            clientWriter.Flush();

            Logger.Debug("Established TCP connection for " + host + ":" + port);

            Thread clientThread =  new Thread(() => TunnelTCP(inClient, outClient));
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(() => TunnelTCP(outClient, inClient));

            clientThread.Start();
            serverThread.Start();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // Disconnent if connections still alive
            Logger.Debug("Closing TCP connection.");
            try
            {
                if (inClient.Connected)
                {
                    inClient.Close();
                }
                if (outClient != null && outClient.Connected)
                {
                    outClient.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Warn("Could not close the tcp connection: ", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tunnels a TCP connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inClient">The client to read from.</param>
    /// <param name="outClient">The client to write to.</param>
    public void TunnelTCP(TcpClient inClient, TcpClient outClient)
    {
        NetworkStream inStream = inClient.GetStream();
        NetworkStream outStream = outClient.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        try
        {
            while (inClient.Connected && outClient.Connected)
            {
                if (inStream.DataAvailable && (read = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    outStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Debug("TCP connection error: ", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            Logger.Debug("Closing TCP connection.");
            // Disconnent if connections still alive
            try
            {
                if (inClient.Connected)
                {
                    inClient.Close();
                }
                if (outClient.Connected)
                {
                    outClient.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                Logger.Warn("Could not close the tcp connection: ", e1);
            }
        }
    }
```